# deleting an object using its ID from pinia array

Tags: vue.js, pinia

how i can delete an object from a pinia array using the object id?

**here is my code**

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";
import { useaCountdownStore } from "../stores/countdowns";

const props = defineProps({
  countdowns: Object,
});

const main = useaCountdownStore();
const countdowns = main.$state.countdowns;

const deleteCountdown = (e) => {
  countdowns = countdowns.filter((countdown) => {
      countdown.id != e.targt.parentElement.id;
    });
};

</script>
<template>
  <div
    class="w-full bg-violet-400 p-2 rounded-md text-violet-950"
    v-for="countdown in countdowns"
    :id="countdown.id"
  >
    <h1>{{ countdown.title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ countdown.date }}</h2>
    <button class="h-10 w-20 bg-red-700" @click="deleteCountdown">
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

and for some reason this is not working! why?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The snippet lacks the context, it's unknown what `array` is, but generally there's no way how a reassigned variable could be reactive in js, not specific to vue or pinia

Comment: countdowns is a const. You can't reassign it in JS. It's a constant.

Comment: @EstusFlask that is correct, use `let` instead ;)

Comment: @Gass Not really, unless that's an inside joke. The point is that a variable that holds reactive value shouldn't be reassigned, it's impossible to properly implement reactivity in js this way.

Comment: that is correct. I meant create another ´let´ variable for the filtered data

Answer (score 0):

`countdowns` shouldn't be reassigned, it's a constant and it can't be reactive the other way.

The problem here is that it was destructured from the state without a good reason.

It should be either:

```
const main = useCountdownStore();
const deleteCountdown = (e) => {
  main.countdowns = main.countdowns.filter((countdown) => {
      countdown.id != e.targt.parentElement.id;
    });
};
```

Or used as a ref:

```
const main = useaCountdownStore();
const { countdowns } = toRefs(main);

const deleteCountdown = (e) => {
  countdowns.value = countdowns.value.filter((countdown) => {
      countdown.id != e.targt.parentElement.id;
    });
};
```

`deleteCountdown` itself implements store logic outside the store, it should preferably be transformed to store action.