# i want to return filterd array that return objects with dates bigger than current date with vue

Tags: vue.js

i have an array of object called `countdowns` ,evry object has property title, date and id
i want to filter the array so it return only dates bigger than the object dates
here is my code and it's return me the same `countdowns` array without filtering it

**here is my code**

```
const currentDate = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  let currentDay = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  let currentMonth = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
  let currentYear = date.getFullYear();
  // we will display the date as DD-MM-YYYY
  let currentDate = `${currentDay}-${currentMonth}-${currentYear}`;
  return currentDate;
};

const noneEndedCountdowns = computed(() => {
  // filters countdowns that only not ended
  return countdowns.value.filter((e) => {
    return e.date >= currentDate();
  });
});
```

Comment: How is `countdowns` defined ? Then for the elements inside, what is the type, contents or format of `date` property ?

Comment: If this question somehow relates to [your previous countdown question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340142/deleting-an-object-using-its-id-from-pinia-array) you can add a link to your post to give context.

Comment: It would help to know what values `countdowns` contains, but it's also apparent `currentDate` retuns a string, and that is **not** what you want.  You want to compare **two date objects**, not strings. Lookup [how to compare dates in JS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-date-comparison-how-to-compare-dates-in-js/), there's also this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994) that should help.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your `e.date` to a date to have a meaningful comparison. Otherwise you compare strings which doesn't make sense.

```
const currentDate = new Date(new Date().toDateString());

const noneEndedCountdowns = computed(() => {
  // filters countdowns that only not ended
  return countdowns.value.filter((e) => {
    const [day, month, year] = e.date.split('-').reverse();
    const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    return e.date >= currentDate;
  });
});
```